# Why can I no longer install Synaptic in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, software-center, synaptic

In Ubuntu 12.04, you have suggested installing the Synaptic Package Manager with `sudo apt-get install synaptic` which didn't work for me.

I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` and also `sudo apt-get update`, but had the same problem.

I did not have these problems on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Please try to install it using the Ubuntu Software Center. I did that and it worked.

Comment: "didn't work for me" is not really specific. What went wrong? Any error messages?

Comment: As @izzy says, please **edit your question** to include the **complete and exact text** of any error messages, including **everything from the command line** when you run those commands (including the lines on which you entered the commands, so we can see *exactly* what you typed). You can run the commands again if you've already closed the Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing through [Synaptic Package Manager page](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/).

It is in Precise Universe Repository , seems you have it disabled, open software sources from Dash >> applications , if not there then through Update Manager >> settings , there you will get like this

[image]

If your ( Universe ) repository is unmarked ,MARK it and reload or do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and try installing it.